# Widget update results in ANR

Tags: java, android, widget

I have a simple app that reads internet resource and displays the information in a widget or in listview activity in form of imageviews and textviews.
In addition to downloading the data from internet it also shows it in widget in a ViewFlipper.

When I add the widget to the home screen, it fires onUpdate immediately, downloads the data from internet and updates the widget. This works just fine. Log shows `onUpdate` and `dataDownloaded` with about 3 sec apart.
On the next update (phone has gone to sleep mode), the update doesn't happen and this is what my logs report.

- onUpdate is called.
- `dataDownloading` is called, but after 20 seconds after `onUpdate` has been initially called. I assume this is because the phone was in sleep and it takes time to initialize networks sockets etc.
- After this, I get the ANR log entry and widget update doesn't happen, process is practically dead, widget stays on screen and doesn't respond to manual updates from within activity, which otherwise works when no ANR exception is thrown.

I'm looking for a possible solution to this. I was thinking about calling all the downloads in a different thread (from within the AppWidgetProvider, possibly using `AsyncTask`), store data in SQLite or local storage and doing the widget  update (no downloads, just reading the data from SQLite and local storage) on the next `onUpdate` call. This would make the application/widget process more responsive and not fault into ANR.

Is this threading approach a bad practice? Is there an alternative? Should I use service instead? I'm inclined not to use a service, unless there's a lot of pros for it.

Sorry for the wall of text :)

**Edit:** From the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

Android will display the ANR dialog for a particular application when it detects one of the following conditions:

- No response to an input event (e.g. key press, screen touch) within 5 seconds
- A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading is the *only* way to safely do network access on Android. So, yes, you'll need to use something like an `ASyncTask` or `IntentService`. Note that a plain `Service` won't be much help, since that runs on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, after reading the docs, I was going for a Service, but you sealed the deal with IntentService. I guess I'll have to do send a broadcast from the service and capture it in `AppWidgetManager.onReceive` and do the visual widget update there.

Comment: Instead of Broadcast you can also use a ResultReceiver.

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing a network request then you need to do so either within an `AsyncTask` or in a `Thread`/`Handler` combination. Here are some links to help:

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)
- [Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)
- [Designing for responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- [Thread documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Handler documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using IntentService and a database backend is the proper way to do it I guess.

But what you never should do is performing such background tasks when the application is not active. Please only download data if your app is in foreground!

As for the widget you should use the "updatePeriodMillis" attribute. The Android system makes sure this is only executed when the widget is visible.

For more hints look at the usual location:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: My widget is set to update every 30 min, but I have a setting in the app that changes this. I default to 3 hours.
How can I do an update if I don't download data every 3 hours? Of course, if the widget is not added to the homescreen, no updates will be done. You had me confused there.

Comment: Well, don't bother. I thought you'd update the widget more frequently.